# How To Upload Excel Data In Laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel

I have problem with importing thousand data into phpMyAdmin. I do import and it just cause null. And I can't input it manually one by one. I need something helpful with that problem.

Thanks if you willing to help me.

Answer (score 1):

As you named phpMyAdmin I guess the problem is importing to the database.
MySQLDumper can help you importing and exporting massive database files:

To use it:

1. Download it from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldumper/
2. Place the content inside your webspace. eg: the `htdocs` folder
3. Start the script in your browser (http://www.yourDomain.de/yourFolder/mysqldumper/). eg: localhost/mysqldumper
4. Follow the Installation assistent

From there you could import or export to an existent database or to a new one.

Comment: can you give me an instructions how to use that ?

Comment: There is an error on step 1:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\mysqldump\inc\mysql.php:257 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\mysqldump\install.php(237): MSD_mysql_connect() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\mysqldump\inc\mysql.php on line 257

Comment: Try to put the folder `mysqldump` in  C:\xampp\htdocs. Outside of Laravel folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to enter it 200,200...:(with chunk)
Ex:

```
//path is the path of excel file uploaded ex: /excel/excel.xlx

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(200, function($results)
{


   });
```